# Populating values for one drop down menu based on selection of another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am new-ish to Ruby on Rails, and working on a project with a series of drop down menus.  I would like for the selection of the first drop down menu to populate the values of the second drop down menu if it is possible.  I am working with Rails 4.0.4 and the views are done with Haml.

Currently my code in the view is:

```
%td= collection_select(:schedule, "subject_id[#{i}]", Subject.all, :id, :prefix, prompt: true)
%td= grouped_collection_select(:schedule, "course_ids[#{i}]", Subject.all, :courses, :prefix, :id, :coursetitle, prompt: true)
```

The grouped collection select has everything separated by subject perfectly, but I would like it to hide all the other subjects' values so that only the subject selected in collection select show.  I did see a video utilizing javascript that did this, but it was a much older version of Rails and no longer works.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: can you show the javascript code that you used which is not working now?

Comment: I just searched for a while to find it and can't.  I trashed it a long time ago.  Sorry!

Comment: I can think of two ways of doing this: A) With ajax (onchange request the matching values) B) With javascript arrays, loading ALL the values categorized on page load. Based on the words you use (course, subject), I assume these tables are very populated, so I'd go for ajax.